# I try to join two table but another table name is in column of first table. Is it possible to join or is there is an

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, join

Joining two tables...one table name is also the column name.
SQL

````
FROM table fs
INNER JOIN fs.tablenamecolumn st 
ON fs.t_ID=st.t_ID
where t=1250```

error--
Invalid object name 'fs.tablenamecolumn '.
````

Comment: You JOIN tables, not columns.

Comment: Not directly ,you would need dynamic sql to do this. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Its better to use self join on table

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I just realised this is for MySQL, Not MSSQL.  SO you will need to use a prepare statement.  hopefully you can use the below as a guide to help you.*

You will need to create the SQL dynamically e.g.

```
DECLARE @tablename AS VARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @tablename = tablnamecolumn FROM [yourtable]

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @query = 
'SELECT * 
 FROM [yourtable] 
 INNER JOIN ' + @tablename + ' 
 ON fs.t_ID=st.t_ID
 WHERE t=1250'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

On where condition give table alias name on column
 the alias name will be on which table you want filtering.

```
select FROM table fs
INNER JOIN fs.tablenamecolumn st 
ON fs.t_ID=st.t_ID
where fs.t=1250
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  This is even quite hard using dynamic SQL because the name might change from row to row.

**You should revisit your data model.**  What you are doing is probably quite unnecessary.

If there is a finite set of tables, you can use `left join`:

```
FROM table fs LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON fs.t_ID = t1.t_ID AND
        fs.tablenamecolumn = 'table1' LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON fs.t_ID = t2.t_ID AND
        fs.tablenamecolumn = 'table2' LEFT JOIN
     . . .
WHERE fs.t = 1250
```